# conditional formatting not following formula

Tags: excel

I have watched many videos and tutorials, and I feel like I must be missing something small here.

My conditional formatting is not conforming to my formula.

I am trying to do a very simple check:

If the value in column E is greater than 30, color the row red, but it seems to be stopping short and missing the last few rows and it is even coloring the table headers, which is outside of the range I have given the formula?

Please see image:
[image]

Comment: your formula should be `=$E1>30` not `=$E2>30`

Comment: Which cell did you have selected when taking this screenshot? As only column E is locked ($E2), it means that row (2) will move with your selection.

Comment: @ScottCraner that worked - but why? I interpreted it to mean "look at every cell from E2 down, and evaluate if it is greater than 30, ignore E1"

Comment: It has to do with your `Applies to:` Range.  The part that iterates should be the upper left cell.  So since you are only iterating the row and using the full column reference then it needs to start on row 1.  If your `Applies to:` Range had been `$A$2:$E$10000` then since the upper row of that range is 2 then the formula you had would have worked.

Comment: Gotcha - Thanks for the explanation! Change your comment to an answer and I can mark it as such.